# converting from array to string, implode didnt work

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables, implode

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "comp4";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id , First_Name, Last_Name FROM member WHERE username='tracy'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["First_Name"]. " " . $row["Last_Name"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}



$conn->close();
?>
```

I have this code in order to display some details about a member in my database but I want to make it into a string and a variable, I tried to use the php implode function but I recieved an error saying that some of the other variables were unexpected any tips or anything wrong that im doing?

Comment: And how exactly did you use `implode()` ?

Comment: Don't see any `implode()` calls in you code!

Comment: You're echoing a string, is that what you want in a variable?

Comment: Did you try something like `implode( ' - ', array_values( $row ) );`

Comment: And what error message do you get?

Answer (score 4):

> Where you used implode()

```
`<?php
      $id = $row["id"];
      $first_name = $row["First_Name"];
      $arr=array ($id,$first_name);
      echo implode(" ",$arr);
    ?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, you should first concatenate all your column in one array, to be then collapsed in one single string as following :

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        // temp variables
        $id = $row["id"];
        $first_name = $row["First_Name"];
        $last_name = $row["Last_Name"];

        $array = array($id, $first_name, $last_name); // creating an array

        $result = implode(" - ", $array); // Collapsing data using dash

        printf($result); // displaying data collapsed
    }
```

from [official php implode doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.implode.php)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried to put that into the code and get an unexpected end of file error which im trying to resolve now

Answer (score 0):

I you want the result in a string, replace the echo by this:
`$results .= "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["First_Name"]. " " . $row["Last_Name"]. "<br>";`

Now everithing is in $results

Answer (score -1):

Here is perfect solution for your problem.. It will work. i am using mysql extension rather than mysqli..

[image]